# Connecting Raspberry PI 3 with Android Things to Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, communication, android-things

My question is about how to communicate Android of Things applications with Arduino. I want to use all the arsenal of sweet sweet cheap Arduino sensors on my Android of Things projects. I have found two source links and tried but I didn't get values.

[image]

```
class Arduino(uartDevice: String = "UART0"): AutoCloseable {
    private val TAG = "Arduino"
    private val uart: UartDevice by lazy {
        PeripheralManagerService().openUartDevice(uartDevice).apply {
            setBaudrate(115200)
            setDataSize(8)
            setParity(UartDevice.PARITY_NONE)
            setStopBits(1)
        }
    }

    fun read(): String {
        val maxCount = 8
        val buffer = ByteArray(maxCount)
        var output = ""
        do {
            val count = uart.read(buffer, buffer.size)
            output += buffer.toReadableString()
            if(count == 0) break
            Log.d(TAG, "Read ${buffer.toReadableString()} $count bytes from peripheral")
        } while (true)
        return output
    }

    private fun ByteArray.toReadableString() = filter { it > 0.toByte() }
            .joinToString(separator = "") { it.toChar().toString() }

    fun write(value: String) {
        val count = uart.write(value.toByteArray(), value.length)
        Log.d(TAG, "Wrote $value $count bytes to peripheral")
    }

    override fun close() {
        uart.close()
    }
}
```

I have found this [Raspberry Pi to Arduino Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642623/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-communication) source on stack but the discussion is not related to my question. I want all the values from arduino to android things RPI 3.

How we can get values from arduino through android framework using java?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/discovering-the-UART-api) project. It has important part: Bi-Directional Logic Level Converter.

Answer (score 4):

The Pi and Arduino have a variety of communication protocols embedded in them. The simplest way would be exchanging data over UART.

Your Arduino code could continually transfer data and the Pi could have code to receive it. If your data doesn't fit in a single byte you could write additional custom logic to encode and decode it.